# does not contain any mapped entities while generating getter and setter

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i am tying to create `one to one` relation in symfony 2 using `doctrine`

here is my entity class

```
<?php

namespace Travel\HomeBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_access_token;



     /** 

     @ORM\Column(name="travel_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Travel\HomeBundle\Entity\Client") 
     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="travel_id", referencedColumnName="id") 

     */

    protected $travel_id;


    /** 

      @ORM\Column(name="travel_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) 
      @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Travel\HomeBundle\Entity\Client")
      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="travel_access_token", referencedColumnName="secret")

     */

    protected $travel_access_token;




    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }


}

?>
```

after updating schema when i run following command to generate getter and setter methods

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Travel/HomeBundle/Entity/User.php
```

i am getting following `Runtime Error`

```
 Namespace "Travel\HomeBundle\Entity\User.php" does not contain any mapped  
   entities.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`doctrine:generate:entities` does not take file extensions. Just remove the `.php`.

The following are example of acceptable parameters for `doctrine:generate:entities`:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Travel/HomeBundle/Entity/User
```

Or

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities TravelHomeBundle:User
```