# symfony2 error: [RuntimeException] Namespace "ProjectBundle\Entity\Mandator" does not contain any mapped entit ies

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, setter, getter

I have a problem in a OneToMany-relationship in Symfony2. I created the entities

Mandator

```
// src/Pso/ProjectBundle/Entity/Mandator.php
   namespace Pso\ProjectBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
    * @ORM\Table(name="mandator", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci",
                 "charset"="utf8", "engine"="InnoDB"})
    * @ORM\Entity()
    */

   class Mandator
  {     
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;


   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Pso\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project",   
      mappedBy="mandator")
    */
    private $projects;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
   */
   private $longname;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
   */
  private $shortname;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();
  }
}
```

and the entity Project, wgich has a relationship to another entity called User

```
// src/Pso/ProjectBundle/Entity/Project.php
namespace Pso\ProjectBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="project", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci", 
             "charset"="utf8", "engine"="InnoDB"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pso\ProjectBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */

class Project
{ 
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
 private $project_nr;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pso\ProjectBundle\Entity\Mandator",  
                  inversedBy="projects")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mandator_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $mandator;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80, nullable=false)
 */
 private $project_name;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
 private $customer;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
 private $label;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
 private $shipping_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 */ 
 private $advance_payment;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=1)
 */
 private $probability;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="blob")
 */
 private $special_demand;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
 */ 
 private $currency;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=1, nullable=false)
 */ 
 private $status;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */  
 private $contract_nr;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */   
 private $dbinsert;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */ 
 private $dbupdate;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User", cascade= 
                  {"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $users;

 public function __construct() {
    $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

When I now try to generate setters and getters with command

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities ProjectBundle/Entity/Mandator
```

or

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities ProjectBundle/Entity/Project
```

I get the error

> [RuntimeException]
>     Namespace "ProjectBundle\Entity\Mandator" does not contain any mapped
>     entities.

I read several topics for example ([topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920474/does-not-contain-any-mapped-entities-while-generating-getter-and-setter), [topic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630802/namespace-doesnt-contain-mapped-entities-in-symfony-2), [topic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231953/symfony2-error-using-doctrinegenerateentities-to-create-getters-and-setters)) without an idea, where my mistake could be.

Comment: It looks like you forgot the root part of your namespace 'Pso'.
Test with `app/console doctrine:generate:entities Pso/ProjectBundle/Entity/Mandator`

Comment: Thx a lot, that is the solution. I didn't see it after a few hours. Sometimes I should make a break. If you make it as an answer I can mark your answer as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the root part of your namespace 'Pso'.

You have to execute :

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities Pso/ProjectBundle/Entity/Mandator
```